How can I add several help arguments using argparse, which don't require adding any required arguments?
I'm using ArgumentParser to document the usage of a complicated program. Since the program has several long lists of capabilities, it requires several --help arguments.
My current ArgumentParser looks like this.
parser = ArgumentParser(description = 'Complicated program')
parser.add_argument('--list-models', action = 'store_true', help = 'List the available models')
parser.add_argument('--list-stuff', action = 'store_true', help = 'List the other stuff')
# ...
parser.add_argument('important_data', help = 'Some important data that is required')

I want --list-models and --list-stuff to print some data and exit, similar to how --help works.
However, running the program with either argument fails since important_data is a positional argument, which ArgumentParser always requires.
What's the nicest way to implement this help pattern?

You definitely don't want action="store_true"; it's slightly hack-y but you could get what you want with action="version" - https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action. It's awkward because what you're doing isn't very standard, maybe they should be subcommands instead.

My approach is to make --important-data optional and check afterward:
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys

parser = ArgumentParser(description="Complicated program")
parser.add_argument(
    "--list-models", action="store_true", help="List the available models"
)
parser.add_argument("--list-stuff", action="store_true", help="List the other stuff")
# ...
parser.add_argument(
    "important_data", nargs="?", help="Some important data that is required"
)

options = parser.parse_args()
print(f"{options=}")

if options.important_data is None and not options.list_models and not options.list_stuff:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

if options.list_models:
    print("list models")
    sys.exit(0)
    
if options.list_stuff:
    print("list stuff")
    sys.exit(0)

# The rest of the code


You can do this by implementing a custom action type. Any object which follows the action API may be passed as the action parameter in add_argument, but the easiest way to do this is to inherit argparse.Action.
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Action, SUPPRESS


class MyAction(Action):

    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest=SUPPRESS, default=SUPPRESS, help=None):
        super().__init__(
            option_strings=option_strings,
            dest=dest,
            default=default,
            nargs=0,
            help=help,
        )

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print(self.help)
        parser.exit()


parser = ArgumentParser(description="Complicated program")
parser.add_argument("--list-models", action=MyAction, help="List the available models")
parser.add_argument("--list-stuff", action=MyAction, help="List the other stuff")
parser.add_argument("important_data", help="Some important data that is required")
args = parser.parse_args()

Adapt this example to your exact needs.
